# What is $a: b: c$ if $a: b$ is $\frac ab$?

Tags: soft-question, fractions, ratio

I was teaching my younger brother the concept of ratios and proportions. I told him that a ratio can be expressed as a quotient of its constituents. For example if we have a ratio $a:b$, we can express it as $\displaystyle\frac ab$. The question he asked after this was really a thought-provoking question for me. He asked:

> If $a:b$ means $\displaystyle\frac ab$, then what does $a:b:c$ mean?

I know that in this case it can't be expressed as a quotient. So is there no other way to express the ratio $a:b:c$ just as we express $a:b$? What should I tell my brother?

Comment: A ratio is not a quotient.

Comment: Ratios express proportions.

Comment: @KennyLau See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLUqczMTb7Y)

Comment: Just because a popular channel propagates the misconception doesn't mean you should believe it.

Comment: And by the way, that Youtube video has 1 like and 3 dislikes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose 
$$a:b:c=x:y:z$$
Then ,
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{x}{y}$$
And
$$\frac{b}{c}=\frac{y}{z}$$

Answer (score 2):

A ratio is not exactly a fraction, but somewhat related. For example saying that $a:b= c:d$ means that there is are constants $\xi\ne 0$ and $\eta\ne 0$(*) such that $\xi a = \eta c$ and $\xi b = \eta d$.

This of course is also true (to some extent) to fractions. If $a/b=c/d$ we have that with $\xi = d$ and $\eta = b$ that $\xi a = \eta c$ and $\xi b= \eta d$.

But when we extend the concept to tripples differences will arise because of the left associativity of division. Fractions are expressions of division while ratios are by definition **not**.

For example we have that $1:2:3=2:4:6$, but $1/2/3 = (1/2)/3 = 1/6$ and $2/4/6=(2/4)/6 = 1/12$ so $1/2/3\ne 2/4/6$.

You still can express such a ratio as a quotient of it's constituents. That you express $a:b$ as $a/b$ means that the first element is $a/b$ times the second. If you want to express a three-way ratio in quotient form you would need to have **two** quotients, for example one between the two first and one between the two last - the ratio $1:2:3$ then is represented by the quotients $1/2$ and $2/3$ (the first is $1/2$ of the second which in turn is $2/3$ of the third).

(*) We can allow one of them being $0$, but that complicates things a bit as then equality of ratios are no longer an equivalence relation.